# PHP Contact form submits without needing all fields filled in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP contact form which works even if the fields are not filled in. This hasn't been a problem until recently when I've started to get handfuls of blank emails every day.

How do enforce all fields to be filled out in the form before the submit button can be used?

Here is my PHP code below:

```
    <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$EmailFrom = "myemail";
$EmailTo = "myemail";
$Subject = "subject goes here";
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) { 
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email  
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom" . "\r\n" );

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"   content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

And here is my HTML markup:

```
                <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
                <div class="span9 contact_form">
                    <div id="note"></div>
                    <div id="fields">
                        <div id="post-ajax" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix" action="/php/contactengine.php">
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
                            <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value     == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
                            <input class="contact_btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- //CONTACT FORM -->
```

Comment: Use if else conditions like **if($EmailFrom!=""){echo 'you error msg. here'; exit;}**  or you can use **jQuery/Javascript** for form validation on Client side.

Comment: you have to validate each field on the client side (Javascript) and then on the server side (PHP) or use the required on html

Comment: @Gacci Could you please show me how you would do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your fields. But in general, HTML5 provides a very convenient way to make a form field required. To do so, you can add a `required` attribute in your form elements, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_name" required />
```

Modern browsers will validate the fields during form submit. To support older browsers, you can use JS validation libraries for client-side validation and use PHP condition check, e.g. `if(!empty($_POST['txt_name']))` for server-side validation.

Moreover, it is suggested not to use meta refresh tag for redirection; use `header('Location: error.htm'); exit;` for example, instead.

---

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="span9 contact_form">
    <div id="note"></div>
    <div id="fields">
        <div id="post-ajax" style="display: none;"></div>
        <form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix" action="/php/contactengine.php">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="Email" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" required />
            <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value     == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';" required>Message</textarea>
            <input class="contact_btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //CONTACT FORM -->
```

Comment: Ive added the fields above...does this help you?

Comment: Yes, as suggested in my answer, adding `required` attribute will solve most of your problem.

Comment: Could you please show me where in my html you would place required?

Comment: Added your form. Also, in modern HTML, we will separate JS from the HTML structure. Please move all the `onFocus` actions to a separate JS script block.

Comment: Ok I've used your HTML but now the submit button does not work

Comment: Define "does not work". Any error in Developer console?

Comment: sorry for being unclear - it simply doesn't submit anymore. Nothing in console either. Something in your new code seems to have stopped the form from sending the message

Comment: Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g26u2pn0/). It works perfectly. Which browser are you working on?

Comment: ok now were are getting somewhere however the onfocus script you advised me to move is no longer working - any ideas

Comment: You can reference this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148949/onfocus-and-onblur-events-on-input) for making onfocus and onblur event

Comment: im so sorry to ask this as you've been very helpful but could you show me how to do this in my HTML as its proving to be beyond my abilities

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding the `required` attribute as indicated in the other answer(which can be by passed very easy through inspect element) you also need validation in the server side as well before processing.

You can create an array of the required fields then check, if those fields are set and not empty.

```
<?php

        $errors = ""; 
        $requiredFields = array("email","message"); // enter the name in the inputs, ie name="someInput"

        foreach($requiredFields as $fieldname){

            if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && empty($_POST[$fieldname])){

                $errors++;

                echo "Enter all fields";

                //OR redirect to error page

            }
        }

        if($errors <=0){

            // Proccess the form

            $EmailFrom = "myemail";
            $EmailTo = "myemail";
            $Subject = "subject goes here";
            $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
            $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

            // prepare email body text
            $Body .= "Email: ";
            $Body .= $Email;
            $Body .= "\n";
            $Body .= "Message: ";
            $Body .= $Message;
            $Body .= "\n";

            // send email  
            $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom" . "\r\n" );

            // redirect to success page 
            if ($success){

               header("location:contactthanks.php");
               exit();
            }
            else{
                header("location:error.htm")

                exit();
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Would ti be possible to show me how you would implement this into my html & php as its not working I'm afraid

Comment: using `die()` is not an user-friendly way to tell the visitor something is missing.